# Android Studio - Unable to connect to device or emulator

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a problem running apps in Android Studio. When I press Run, the "Select Deployment Target" dialog popup occurs, but I am never able to see any emulators or devices occur. The event log prints out the following and repeats indefinitely:

```
5/6/18
12:40 PM    Gradle sync started

12:40 PM    Project setup started

12:41 PM    Gradle sync finished in 49s 932ms

12:41 PM    Executing tasks: [:app:generateDebugSources]

12:41 PM    Gradle build finished in 15s 765ms

12:44 PM    Unable to open connection to: localhost/0.0.0.0:5037, due to: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

12:44 PM    Connection attempts: 1

12:44 PM    Unable to open connection to: localhost/0.0.0.0:5037, due to: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

12:44 PM    Connection attempts: 2

12:44 PM    Unable to open connection to: localhost/0.0.0.0:5037, due to: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

12:44 PM    Connection attempts: 3

12:44 PM    Unable to open connection to: localhost/0.0.0.0:5037, due to: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

12:44 PM    Connection attempts: 4

12:44 PM    Unable to open connection to: localhost/0.0.0.0:5037, due to: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused

12:44 PM    Connection attempts: 5
```

I am able to run react-native projects using the command line, but when using Android Studio directly, this occurs.

I have tried creating new projects in Android Studio and still have the same results. I believe this started to happen once I updated from Android Studio 3.0 to 3.1.

Any ideas to fix this issue or get more information?

Thanks.

System Information:

MacOS High Sierra 10.3.14
Macbook Pro (Late 2011)

Software Information:

Android Studio 3.1.2
Java 9.0.4

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had the same issue, i fixed it by removing `0.0.0.0` mapping in `/etc/hosts`.

Earlier i had a mapping `0.0.0.0 localhost` in `/etc/hosts` file.

Comment: This works. Thanks. I wonder why this mapping started to be a problem as I had it for a long time.

Comment: Can someone explain why that is a problem and how adding or removing stuff in /etc/hosts solves this issue?

Answer (score 4):

I also had a similar issue on Mac and fixed it by appending the line ***127.0.0.1 localhost*** to /etc/hosts

Answer (score 2):

I also had a similar issue on Mac and fixed it by removing the line
**::1     localhost**  from /private/etc/hosts.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I resolved it using 10.0.2.2 instead of 0.0.0.0 for default AVD. I will hit 0.0.0.0 and work. Add the port with it as you desire. Add it in network-security-config too for cleartextTrafficPermitted.

10.0.2.2 is a Special alias to your host loopback interface (127.0.0.1 on your development machine)

If you are Genymotion emulator - use 10.0.3.2.